# How do i check if values are the same in two dataframes based on a unique identifier in a for loop? PYTHON

Tags: python

I have 2 dataframes and I want to check in a for loop if the values at each unique identifier matches.

df1:

```
id|treat
---|---
123|ice cream
456|cake
789|cookie
```

df2:

```
     id|treat
    —--|—--
    456|cake
    789|cookie
    123|cake
```

i want to do a for loop that checks if the `treat` value is the same in each data frame based on their `id`

ex: i want to check if `456` has the same value in df1 and df2 - but for all values and keep a running check of how many match.

Thank you!!!

```
matches = 0
frames = zip(df1, df2)
  for x,y, in frames:  
    if x["treats"] == y["treats"]:
      matches+=1
```

this also doesn't work but unclear why?

```
for row in range(len(df1)):
    idd = df1.iloc[row]['id']
    if idd in df2['id'].values:
        if (df1.iloc[row]['treat']=='cake') and (df2[df2['id'] == idd]['treat'] == 'cake'):
            matched+= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through id values, check if it exists in other DF and if so, check the `treat` column.
Something along these lines:

```
for row in range(len(df1)):
    idd = df1.iloc[row]['id']
    if idd in df2['id'].values:
        print(df1.iloc[row]['treat'] == df2[df2['id'] == idd]['treat'])
```

Comment: why does doing this not work? for row in range(len(df1)):
    idd = df1.iloc[row]['id']
    if idd in df2['id'].values:
        if (df1.iloc[row]['treat']=='cake') and (df2[df2['id'] == idd]['treat'] == 'cake'):
            matched+= 1
etc etc

Comment: When I run that code, this part causes an error: `(df2[df2['id'] == idd]['treat'] == 'cake')`, because this is still a `pd.Series` type. Instead, you can change the `pd.Series` to a `np.ndarrray` type and it's resolved: `(df2[df2['id'] == idd]['treat'].values == 'cake')`